# Excel: conditional running total formula based of value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel file with two sheets like below

[image]

and

[image]

In the Donations sheet in Column F, I'd like to subtract the sum of Column E from the cell in column D in Paychecks sheet in which the value of ID matches the PID from the Donations sheet. Kinda like I've shown in quotes in the image above.

I can get the proper value from Paycheck sheet from column D by using VLOOKUP (my formula: `ROUNDUP(VLOOKUP(D2,Paychecks!A:B,2)*0.1,0)` but how do I keep the running total of column E only if the values of column D are the same?

Comment: [`SUMIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b), maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cybernetic.nomad is on to something. Try this formula in cell F2.

```
=ROUNDUP(VLOOKUP(D2,Paychecks!A:B,2)*0.1,0)-SUMIF(D$1:D2,D2,E:E)
```

The first half (minuend) is your formula to acquire the dollar value displayed in Paycheck!D2.

The second half (subtrahend†) is a sumif. In three parts, it looks for the PIDs that match the PID in D2 from the top to the current row only. It then sums every matching row's column E.

† Learned something new today (or relearned something long and firmly forgotten)

Comment: Works beautifully!! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad it worked out.